# JSON Parsing result error

Tags: jquery, json

I am parsing the string returned from Cakephp 2.0 Controller..

My Autocomplete code is..

```
jQuery("#name").autocomplete( '<?php echo HTTP_PATH.'/lensmaterials/getBrands'; ?>', {
    multiple: true,
    mustMatch: true,
    matchContains: true,
    autoFill: false,
    dataType: "json",
    parse: function(data) {
        return $.map(data, function(item) {
            return { data: item, value: item.label, result: item.label};
        });
    },
    formatItem: function(item) {
        return '<li>' + item.label + '</li>';
    }
});
```

I am getting list like Value, than undefined , than value than undefined.
Its ending me with error in firebug. If I select than value is not entered in my textbox.
I want the Value in beautiful way. That is Div showing list in ul, li...

My Controller code is..

```
public function getBrands(){
    $brandList = $this->Brand->find('list',array('fields'=>array('id','brand_name'),'order' => array('Brand.brand_name')));
    //pr($brandList); exit;
    foreach ($brandList as $key => $name) {
        $json_output[]['id'] = $key;
        $json_output[]['label'] = $name;
    }
    echo json_encode($json_output);
    $this->autoRender = false;
}
```

Returning JSON string is

```
 [{"id":1},{"label":"Bvlgari"},{"id":2},{"label":"Chanel"},{"id":7},{"label":"D & G"},{"id":8},{"label":"Dior"},{"id":10},{"label":"Emporio Armani"},{"id":11},{"label":"Fendi"},{"id":12},{"label":"Giorgio Armani"},{"id":13},{"label":"Gucci"},{"id":14},{"label":"Oakley"},{"id":15},{"label":"Oliver Peoples"},{"id":16},{"label":"Paul Smith"},{"id":4},{"label":"Polo Ralph Lauren"},{"id":18},{"label":"Prada"},{"id":19},{"label":"Prada Linea Rossa"},{"id":20},{"label":"Ray Ban"},{"id":21},{"label":"Tiffany"},{"id":3},{"label":"Tom Ford"}]
```

Final its not returning as I type. That is I have Chanel and if I type than unformatted and undefined never continue with my keyup. It remains constant.

Comment: What is the error? Could you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo?

Comment: `s is undefined
[Break On This Error] s = s.toLowerCase(); `
This is the error

Checked it jsonlint.com Its validating correct

Comment: `json_encode` will always create valid JSON, but that does not mean that the application understands the data you pass to it. The the data also has to be structure so that it is understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your data format is wrong. The `id` and `label` properties should be in the same object. Half of your objects don't have a `label` property, so trying to access it will result in `undefined` (i.e. you get `{data: {...}, value: undefined, result: undefined}`).

Change your generation process to:

```
foreach ($brandList as $key => $name) {
    $json_output[] = array('id' => $key, 'label' => $name);
}
```

Then the output will be:

```
[{"id":1,"label":"Bvlgari"},{"id":2,"label":"Chanel"},...]
```

Comment: Ya its generating correct list now. But still 2 issues. First is Its listing quite slow. Second If I select any value than Its not filling in my textbox.. Third is desinging in div... i.e ul, li

Comment: You should only ask one question per question. Regarding setting the value of the textbox, maybe `autoFill` has something to do with it? You don't seem to use the autocomplete plugin from jQuery UI, so without more information, we cannot help you. As for designing, if you formulate it as a proper question and give examples, you might get some help. Otherwise it seems you just want to get someone to do your work.

Comment: Can u help me with other three issues. I have mentioned..I can't vote you up as below 15 reputation else I would...

Comment: Sorry but its not like that Today only I have come across JSON. I googled it very much didn't find any solution yet. You cleared my problem Thanks for that. Would be bit more happy to get helped from you. Even I got my fault...

Comment: We can only help you if you we understand the problem. As I said, we don't know which plugin you use, hence we cannot help you with the plugin. Second, *I want the Value in beautiful way. That is Div showing list in ul, li*... well how should this look like? How does it look like now? And again, this probably depends on the plugin you are using. The more information you provide, the better you explain your problem, the better answers you get.